# Would it be possible to have fresh water in a world where there was a major volcanic eruption which destroyed all civilisation apart from one city?

Tags: water, volcanoes

For an area in a world I am creating, 300 years prior to the present day, the northlands were destroyed by major volcanic eruptions. Would it be possible for there to be water accessible to a party journeying through these 'Ashlands' or would there be too much volcanic contamination?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you consider volcanic contamination.  The effects of these eruptions would have thrown the world into a century long nuclear winter as well, this wouldn't be an isolated event.  'one city' wouldn't like survive either, changing land makes centralization more difficult.  Ash wouldn't exist very long either...wind and rain remove it over years.   Mind describing your world a bit better?

Comment: For my world, the city that did survive was kept so by a supernatural force that the people refer to as the Guardian. In the North, the people are surrounded by volcanoes and worship the fire. An event 300 years prior saw the elements unsettle. Maelstroms affected the Souther tribe, winds attacked the Western tribe, earthquakes decimated the Eastern tribe and volcanic eruptions crippled the North. For the last 300 years, these tribes have isolated themselves and began to rebuild. With a new event, the a party from the North needs to travel a month in the wastes.

Comment: What wastes? Volcanic ash is known to be extremely fertile. After a few decades the edges would be teaming with flora. Moving in more and more over the centuries.

Comment: That is a good point. That was a major oversight on my behalf. Can we assume that this world - which is a fantasy world - has been completely destroyed by lava, fire and the other associated madnesses that come with volcanic eruption. In this area, there is always a volcano in view and there is barely an area that hasn't been completely covered in molten rock. After years the rock has solidified, so would the fertile ash be able to produce flora on top of that rock?

Comment: Volcanic ash is also one of the best natural water filters in existence.  Water and vegitation should be quite lush 300 years later.  If there is current volcanic activity, sulfur tends to be the major contaminant to be wary of....it needs to be a constantly exposed to new sources of sulfur though...it wouldnt remain long.  Are you familiar with iceland or hawaiis terrain?  Former volcanic land is exceedingly fertile

Comment: An extention...fire is part of the cycle of life on earth.  Many northern tree species actually depend on a forest fire to decimate a forest as part of their seed cycles (pine cones 'activate' with fire).  Fire is rebirth within nature and does not remain burnt landscap for long.  You would need a force that is constantly enforcing this burn.

Comment: At the point where the story begins, the volcanoes are once again becoming active, so there would be sulphur and various other gasses beginning to escape into the atmosphere. I can definitely change the landscape to be fertile and perhaps use this to make the ruins of the old civilisation reclaimed by the vegetation. Would the vegetation growth be solely on low lying areas or would the volcanoes themselves have some vegetation creeping up the sides? The biggest volcano I envisaged was going to be almost one and a half times the size of Mt Everest.

Comment: @Wingly21 If your world has the same structure as earth than it is pretty much impossible to have a volcano of that size (1.5 times as tall as Mount Everest).

Comment: It's a fantasy world with similarities to Earth but its not the same, things are much bigger in this world such as the mountains, expanses of land, the seas etc.

Comment: [Hawaii](https://www.gohawaii.com/statewide/discover/essential-hawaii/volcanoes-of-hawaii/) has three active volcanoes.  Note that one of them is more massive than Everest but shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! I think fresh water sources like rivers and big lakes will provide quite potable water.

300 years is a very long time. After 300 cycles of rain, water in surroundings will no longer be acidic due to all those oxides of sulfur and nitrogen. The SPM will settle down. That means, no longer turbid water. In fact, life would be flourishing because of rich nutrients which were ejected in the eruption.

In a nutshell, 300 years is quite long time for any contamination to persist in ecosystem, answer could be different for less than 50 years.

Answer (score 0):

300 years is more than enough. In 1985  Nevado del Ruiz volcano erupted. The near city of Manizales wasn't even affected and the main source of production in the city is coffee. 
Deep containers of water can be blocked by the eruption rather than contaminated. 
And remember that acidulous waters are considered spa waters.